# JList to frame from JComboBox selection

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jlist

I have .txt files and I read them to a `JList`, then I want to select a name of a file from a `JComboBox`, read that file, create the list and appear on the frame inside of a `JScrollPane`.

I have almost everything working the only problem is that I can't add the scroll pane with the list to the frame correctly and the list only appears when I press the button "envia". The way I have my code inserting the list to the scroll pane and then to the window is not correct because the scroll pane are being inserted on top of each other, but its the closest I got to wokring.

I want it to appear on the the scroll pane and on the frame  correctly when I press on the combo box and not when I press "envia".  I don't understand why the list only appears when I press that button.

```
combo2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            falarpara = combo2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            try {
                lista = f.getList(user, falarpara);             
                janela.add(lista.getlist());
                JScrollPane j = new JScrollPane(lista.getlist());
                janela.add(j);
                janela.validate();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e4) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e4.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    envia.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String a = new String(user + ":" + " " + txt.getText());
            f.escreve(user, falarpara, a);
            lista.add(a);
            txt.setText(null);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Pre add the empty JList to the screen when you setup the primary ui. After this, just the list's model

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Add the list at start-up, but change the model on data acquisition (the combo is activated).

Comment: Perfect guys thanks alot.

Comment: Now how to mark this solved.....

Comment: You could add your own answer and mark is accepted